# Ordering with multi level nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So I've been trying to order this:

## gig.rb

```
Class Gigenrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gigenrollments, dependent: :destroy
```

## gigenrollment.rb

```
Class Gigenrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :profile

  def self.order_by_instrument
    includes(profile: :instruments).order(profiles: {instruments: {primary: :desc}})
  end
```

## profile.rb

```
Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :gigenrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instruments, -> {order(primary: :desc)}, dependent: :destroy
```

## instrument.rb

```
Class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
```

I have one way of getting the right order, but it's kind of ugly. It looks like this in the controller:

```
# @gig is an instance of the Gig class, eg. Gig.last
@orchestra = @gig.gigenrollments
@orchestra = @orchestra.sort_by{ |ge| ge.profile.instruments.find_by(primary: true).nil? ? 'z'  : ge.profile.instruments.find_by(primary: true).name}
```

So I'm trying to figure out a neater way to order gig enrollments from one gig depending on one profiles primary instruments name (one profile should have none or more). So far I think I've got the includes correct but I can't find an example of an order that has nested attributes like I have.

So far I have done this in my controller in hope to get what I want:

```
@orchestra = @gig.gigenrollments
@orchestra = @orchestra.order_by_instrument # check out the order_by_instrument function in the code snippet in gigenrollment.rb
```

But the error I get is

```
Direction should be :asc or :desc
```

Which leaves me to think that I just can't get the syntax right. I have also tried this without success

```
# gigenrollment.rb
def self.order_by_instrument
  includes(profile: :instruments).references(profile: :instruments).order('"profile"."instruments"."primary" ASC, "profile"."instruments"."name" ASC')
end
```

I've been reading [this about includes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) and [this about order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) and several posts about this topic on Stackoverflow, but they all seem to have either nested attributes in only one level (I have two, gigenrollments -> profile -> instruments), they are using scopes, have forms or then they have a where clause instead of order, which doesn't really get me to where I would want (wrong syntax). I also found some issues on Github that made me think that it should be doable.

But I kind of get the picture that this isn't doable with an order as one profile can have many instruments and only the instruments with the attribute 'primary' as true should affect the ordering of the gigenrollments, while I'm writing this question.

---

Apparently I need reputation to post links so I have them here instead...

The stackoverflow pages:
  stackoverflow.com/questions/23121975/how-can-i-order-nested-includes-records-with-rails-4
  stackoverflow.com/questions/19865208/rails-query-join-order-by-group-by-issue
  stackoverflow.com/questions/13619560/rails-y-way-to-query-a-model-with-a-belongs-to-association

Github issues:
  github.com/rails/rails/issues/8663
  github.com/rails/rails/issues/726